# Best practice to test non-functional requirements in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, tdd

What is the best practice to test non-functional requirements in a rails 3 application like authentication or authorization which are implemented as before filter in the controllers. Should the functional tests are used where may be the existence of the certain before filters are checked or is it an issue for the integration tests where you try login with wrong credentials.

I have read a lot of other posts but didn’t find a proper solution.

Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of functional tests for a given controller I will usually include the tests such as "make sure the user is redirected to the login page if not logged in", or "make sure the index page is rendered if the user IS logged in".

Ultimately I think it is a style decision, but I consider what is protected via login and what is not, to be part of the functional spec of the application. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what is when the most actions requires login and there are diffrent authorization levels? Do you write a test for each possible combination and fill the functional tests with a lot of non-functional tests?

Comment: Generally I'm using a framework like rspec or shoulda that lets me add a "before" type filter to the different tests and inside of there I put a call to a helper that logs in before the real test in run. To answer the other part of your question, I do test both the logged in and logged out state of each action of the controller(s) in question, often there are some actions that are protected and some that aren't, depending on role, etc.